# Regex negative lookbehind with quantifiers

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to correct some OCR errors and I need to replace `''` (double apex) with `"` ( quotation marks). I'm using Subtitledit (I think it uses C# Regex).

I need to match `''` every time but not in this situation:

```
some text 'undefined length phrase/phrases''
```

the first  `'` should be preceded by a whitespace and followed by a `\w`.

Basically I want to match `''` if it's not preceded by `\s'\w.*`.
In this example:

```
''E poi disse: 'Ne voglio un po'', ed andò via.''
```

I want to match the first and the last `''` but non the one in the middle because it is preceded by `'Ne voglio un po`.

I tried [this](https://regex101.com/r/tJvDrA/1) but it doesn't work because quantifiers can't be used inside a lookbehind.

Comment: So, you want `(?<!\S)''\b`? See https://regex101.com/r/jvEqXl/1

Comment: "_not in this situation_" How **precisely** is _this situation_ defined? You give just one example that can be interpreted in a number of different ways. As i understand it, you want to replace `''` unless those `''` are the very last two characters in the text string. (In other words, you want to replace `''` that is _not_ followed by the end of text. Or in other words again: you you want to replace `''` that is followed by some character.)

Comment: I want to match '' if it's not preceded by    \s'\w.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match them both as delimiters.
In your case it's `''` that you're looking to match as 2 delimiters.

This is how that's done

Find  `('')((?:(?:(?!''|'[^']*'')[\S\s])*(?:'[^']*'')?)*)('')`
Replace `"$2"`

https://regex101.com/r/Ii0aPe/1

**_______________________________________**

If the above doesn't work for you , you can drop the first `('')` and run
it.

**update** - Also, add the middle part to the end for symmetry to cover
the end condition.

*Note this caveat: a string that just contains `'Ne voglio un po''`

will be converted to `'Ne voglio un po"`.

This is what happens when you don't do balanced delimiters.*

Find: `((?:(?:(?!''|'[^']*'')[\S\s])*(?:'[^']*'')?)*)('')((?:(?:(?!''|'[^']*'')[\S\s])*(?:'[^']*'')?)*)`
Replace: `$1"$3`

https://regex101.com/r/KTYhmq/1

Expanded

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      (?:
           (?:
                (?! '' | ' [^']* '' )
                [\S\s] 
           )*
           (?: ' [^']* '' )?
      )*
 )                             # (1 end)
 ( '' )                        # (2)
 (                             # (3 start)
      (?:
           (?:
                (?! '' | ' [^']* '' )
                [\S\s] 
           )*
           (?: ' [^']* '' )?
      )*
 )                             # (3 end)
```

Comment: This is the best solution so far but it does not work if the first '' is not present. https://regex101.com/r/Ii0aPe/2

Comment: @TeodorPatriche - Try the alternative I posted then. https://regex101.com/r/PH3FPz/1

Comment: I think I had a brain fart there and didn't realize you gave me an alternative. The second one works beautifully! Awesome! I need to wrap my head around it to figure out how you managed to do it because I struggled so much trying to make this regex. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @TeodorPatriche - One more change you better check out, along with a caveat.

Answer (score 0):

This expression is pretty interesting, we would be then adding a right side boundary and we would likely start with an expression such as:

```
\s'.+?\w'[^']
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/kK5FOK/1/)

If we have other instances, we could surely expand on this expression with additional constraints, such as:

```
\s'[^']+?\w'[^']
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/3fqHj7/1/)

or

```
\s'\w[^']+?\w'[^']
```

#### [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/GS8hMB/1/)

Comment: I want to match '' actually. I updated the original post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with a 3 regex solution.

1. I temporarily replaced the problematic portion with a combination of characters that I know cannot be found anywhere else in the text. I chose §£, like [this](https://regex101.com/r/iQI9YL/2).
2. Then simply replaced '' with ", like [this](https://regex101.com/r/oUMiAC/2).
3. Finally, replaced §£ so everything is restored as it was. Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/tEP8bi/2).